# convert loop into vectorized computation in Java

Tags: python, android, numpy-ndarray

I would like to convert this part into vector for faster computation like the NumPy Nd array. Due to this, actual FPS is getting dropped.

How can we achieve or make it better?

```
public static List<Double> rgbMean (Mat mat) {
  double R=0,G=0,B=0,ctr=0;
  for (int i=0; i<480; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<640; j++) {
        double[] d = mat.get(i, j);
        R += d[0];
        G += d[1];
        B += d[2];
        ctr+=1;
    }
 }
 double R_ch = R/ctr ;
 double G_ch = G/ctr ;
 double B_ch = B/ctr ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a 2D matrix(image) with arbitrary number of channels, you can use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) `mean` function:

```py
import numpy as np
n, m, c = 480, 640, 3

mat = np.random.random((n, m, c))

average = np.mean(mat, axis=-1)
# Output n x m
```

However, if you want to compute the average of all values in R, G, B channels separately and generate 3 numbers, you can use:

```py
np.mean(mat.reshape(-1, c), axis=0)
# Output: 1 x c
```